# Clojure style, anything like --> with doto semantics?

Tags: clojure

I'm starting to use clojure to test a java library. So my question is more "what is the clojure way of doing this".

I have a lot of code that looks like the following

```
...
 (with-open [fs (create-filesystem)]
    (let [root (.getFile fs path)]
       (is (.isDirectory root))
       (is (.isComplete root)))
    (let [suc (.getFile fs (str path "/_SUCCESS"))]
       (is (.isFile suc))
       (is (.isComplete suc))))
```

Since this is a java object, I need to verify a set of properties are true on the object.  I know about doto that will let me do things like

```
(doto (.getFile fs path)
  (.setPath path2)
  (.setName name2))
```

and --> will let me have a list of partial functions and have each result pass through each function. Been thinking that something like --> but keeps passing the same object like doto would help with these tests.  Would something like this be a good way to do this, or am I not really doing this the clojure way?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`doto`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto):

```
(doto (.getFile fs path) (.setPath path2) (.setPath name2))
```

Comment: Need to use the is function for testing the boolean functions. So doto doesn't do this for me

Answer (score 1):

You may learn about other threading macros like `cond->`, `as->`, `some->` etc... for "the Clojure way" purpose.

There's no macro that does exactly what you wanted. Only `..` and `doto` are object-specific macros.

Because your question is more "the Clojure way" thing, I recommend this:

https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide

Comment: just to clarify, doto is not object specific, and is quite useful in non-object circumstances (such as spying on a value: `(doto 10 (prn "***"))`) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`..` macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/_..) for java interop with threading semantics.

Example:

```
(.. (SomeObject/newBuilder)
    (withId 1)
    (withFooEnabled true)
    (build))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using a let as you have; it is a very direct and clear implementation of what you want to do. I think it is the best approach :)

But it is interesting to examine how you could achieve this with Clojure built in macros too:

```
(doto (.getFile fs path)
  (-> (.isDirectory) (is))
  (-> (.isComplete) (is)))
```

`doto` is special in that it propagates the initial value. It takes subsequent forms and inserts the initial value into the second position of the forms.

`->` allows you to arrange forms inside out... which means you can combine it with `doto` such that the initial value is threaded through whatever layers of forms you would like to execute on it.

Now `doto` and `->` are macros, so the syntax can be a little confusing... if you prefer to use functions then `juxt` is handy for calling multiple functions:

```
((juxt #(is (.isDirectory %)) #(is (.isComplete))) (.getFile fs path))
```

But for this situation it's quite ugly :)

Coming back to your original question, you can of course also create your own syntax with a macro... I describe one approach here: http://timothypratley.blogspot.pt/2016/05/composing-test-assertions-in-pipeline.html which chains multiple assertions in a convenient way.

I think for the example you describe sticking with a `let` form is the best way as it is most obvious... the other forms are shown here to discuss the options available, some of which might be appropriate in other circumstances.